# Configuring SQL Server 2019 Always ON between 2 Azure reqions

Tags: sql-server, azure, high-availability, availability-groups

I have SQL Server on Azure VM which I want to replicate across a separate region. I will only be using 2 servers, each in a separate region. I have the following questions as I need to clear all doubts about this implementation

1. Since they are in separate region, i found in microsoft docs and several online document that an asynchronous commit is recommended, what if i try to use a synchronous commit so that i can implement automatic failover? Are there any possible issues with synchronous commit considering my scenario
2. I also know that to avoid split brain issues I will need to configure Azure cluster Cloud witness to achieve the odd quorum votes. Considering my scenario of just 2 servers in different region, which region is better to configure this cloud witness.
3. Since I am using SQL Server Azure VM will I need a load balancer and consdering the information on this site https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/configuring-sql-server-always-on-azure-serversiaas
   Do I really need a load balancer?

Thanks for your assistance

I have read Microsoft documents to see the requirements for I have further questions

Comment: 1. You can do Synchronous Commit across regions, but you should be mindful of increased latency. If you've chosen a region pair then this is reduced

2. I would use an Azure Storage Account in a third region geographically close to the other two. I.e. if your SQL nodes are in West and North Europe, put the Cloud Witness in UK South or West

3. You don't need a Load Balancer if you're using a recent version of Windows and SQL, you simply add an additional IP address onto each NIC of your VM and use that as the listener IP

Comment: For point 3, this is the Microsoft Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-prerequisites-tutorial-multi-subnet?view=azuresql

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I appreciate your input. 
I am not sure there is a third region, i am thinking of putting the cloud witness at the DR region (close to the read only node) so that their can be automatic failover when the region 1 (primary node region) is down.

Also, looking at the diagram in the link you provided, which speaks to the same region but a different zone. Does that apply to my own scenarios of 2 separate regions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What regions are you choosing for your deployment?

It's the same concept, but rather than being an additional subnet within the vNET same region it's a subnet within an additional vNET in the 2nd region

Comment: Thanks Anthony, regions are UK south and West. 
Where do you think is appropriate to have the cloud witness. Is it the site close to the primary node or DR node as i dont have a third region in my environment

Comment: I would choose North or West Europe; both are geographically close (Ireland and The Netherlands) so latency wouldn't be a problem

Comment: thanks for your response. 
I just checked the region-by-region latency by looking at the site below 
https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/RegionToRegionLatency and found that the latency between UK South and UK West is 5ms while North and West Europe is 12ms. 

Could it be that I am misinterpreting your response?

The region in our environment is UK South and West and I wanted to be sure which region is appropriate to host the cloud witness should I do not have the option of hosting it in the 3rd region.

Thanks for your assistance so far.

Comment: So you need your cloud witness to be in a completely separate region from your nodes, because in the event of a regional failure you need to ensure you have 2 votes remaining. There is no third region in Azure, in that they only have [regional pairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/cross-region-replication-azure#azure-paired-regions). Therefore, you should choose a third region that is geographically nearby. What's your concern over the 7ms difference in latency for the cloud witness?

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, you have been helpful. I will put this forward with the team. 

Once again thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome. Feel free to ask any other questions you might have

Comment: Hi Anthony, I have another question, what happens if I eventually have a separate region for the cloud witness, and the region becomes goes down for a while? The consequence might lead to a split-brain situation, right? 

Also, is there anyway to prevent this.

Comment: There's only so much you can reasonably account for when it comes to redundancy; if the third region where the cloud witness is goes offline, just recreate the cloud witness in another region

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do Synchronous Commit across regions, but you should be mindful of increased latency. If you've chosen a region pair then this is reduced
2. I would use an Azure Storage Account in a third region geographically close to the other two. I.e. if your SQL nodes are in West and North Europe, put the Cloud Witness in UK South or West
3. You don't need a Load Balancer if you're using a recent version of Windows and SQL, you simply add an additional IP address onto each NIC of your VM and use that as the listener IP. The diagram approaches it as a separate subnet in the same vNET, but the principal applies across vNETs and regions as well [Microsoft Doc on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-prerequisites-tutorial-multi-subnet?view=azuresql)